# System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: entity' i get this error while using POST methode

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

hi please anyone can help solving this problem when i use POSTMAN i was able to post data to database. But when im calling POST Methode i got this error. I guess the problem the parameter that i pass to API Controller is null. How can i fix this

Customer Model

```
    public class Customers
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

MVC CONTROLLER

```
        public ActionResult New(Customers customers)
    {
       
        return View(customers);
    }
```

WEB API CONTROLLER

```
        // create customer
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult CreateCustomer(Customers CustomerDTO)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
      
        _context.Customerss.Add(CustomerDTO);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return Created(new Uri(Request.RequestUri + "/" + CustomerDTO.Id), CustomerDTO);

    }
```

VIEW

```
@model API.Models.Customers


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "New";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>New Form</h2>

<div id="container">
    <form>
        <div class="form-group" id="NameGroup">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary js-Add">Save</button>
    </form>
</div>


@section scripts {

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            
            $("#container .js-Add").on("click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                if (confirm("Are you sure you want to ADD this customer?")) {

                    var input = $("Name").val();

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "../api/Customer",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: JSON.stringify(input),
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (response) {
                            alert('HELLO' + response.Name);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Is there a possible type with `Customerss`?

Comment: public DbSet<Customers> Customerss { get; set; }

Answer (score 0):

You have problem in view. you are trying to get value from DOM element which has id as `Name`. However, you have not specified it anywhere.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control", id = "Name" })
```

OR

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(item => item.OperationNo, htmlAttributes: new { id = "Name", class = "form-control" })
```

Update:

```
@section scripts {

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        
        $("#container .js-Add").on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to ADD this customer?")) {

                var input = $("Name").val();
                var request = { Name: input };

                $.ajax({
                    url: "../api/Customer",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify(request),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert('HELLO' + response.Name);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help but still i have the same problem

Comment: @patrick I have updated an answer, Please check again

Comment: thank you for your effort, i did'nt get any error but the alert did not work and no data was added to database